# Why does this not work with Firefox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, browser-support

So, this is based on `WordPress`. Here is the blog on safari and on firefox, what is wrong, likely with the css, since firefox it is not displaying the page correctly?

**on safari (, mouse hover on first post)**
[image]

**on firefox**
[image]

[**html (with php)**](http://pastebin.com/ms9tnFMb) - pastebin link

[**html (generated)**](http://pastebin.com/HhKfg5Zr) - pastebin link

[**css**](http://pastebin.com/erFcYJRK) - pastebin link

**the first grayed element on firefox is this**
[image: http://cl.ly/image/321l1c1u2z2C]

---

### Added a jsfiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LBWe5/1/)**

Comment: html (with php): http://pastebin.com/ms9tnFMb / html (generated):  http://pastebin.com/HhKfg5Zr / css: http://pastebin.com/erFcYJRK / first grayed element on firefox: http://cl.ly/image/321l1c1u2z2C

Comment: You need to post your code and preferably a test case showing the issue. jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's on my local test server, and on wordpress, jsfiddle is not very helpful here? All the code is linked there already, or is it better if I post it in here, it's going to be a long page then.

Comment: @Roope, we can't access your local server, so in order to run this and get access to all the details in the debugging tools, we'd need to completely replicate it in OUR local environments. That's where the fiddle comes in handy.

Comment: @Pete Scott, try this, does it work? http://jsfiddle.net/5XHZ8/1/

Comment: @Martin Turjak, you are a great man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "display:moz-box;" applied to .post-holder is preventing the images from showing up. Looking into WHY now.

I haven't messed with flex-box layouts much at all, so this is largely assumptions. You have a "display:mox-box;" set on .post-holder, but .post-image neglects to set any flexbox properties. Adding "-moz-box-flex: 1;" to .post-image causes the images to display, but likely are not the size you're shooting for.

Comment: There are some interesting bits about the differences between webkit's and mozilla's flexbox implementation here: http://blog.isotoma.com/2010/08/css3-flexbox/ ... might prove useful.

Comment: Thanks for finding the cause, I'll try to go around it somehow now!